# How to active a function only if dedicated button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm at coding a multi step form and have a question:
Is it possible in JavaScript or jQuery to activate this validation script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        // Validation
        $("#sky-form").validate({                   
            // Rules for form validation
            rules: {
                country:  { required: true },
                industry: { required: true },
                logoname: { required: true },
                sloganch: { required: true }
            },                 
            // Messages for form validation
            messages: {
                country:  { required: 'Please enter your name' },
                industry: { required: 'Please check one of the options' },
                logoname: { required: 'Please enter your Logo name' },
                sloganch: { required: 'Please check one of the options' }       
            },
            // Do not change code below
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Only when this button is clicked :

```html
<button type="button1" class="button next action-button"  id="button4">Next</button>
```

It would be nice if the `id="button 4"` determine this function.

Comment: Wrap your code in button click handler, `$('#button4').click(function(){ //.....})`

Comment: thank you Setpal you made my day its working as i wanted , have a nice day

Comment: Mate Glad I could help, Please use correct name of a person.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$('#button4').click(function() {
$("#sky-form").validate({                   
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            country: { required: true },
            industry: { required: true },
            logoname: { required: true },
            sloganch: { required: true }
        },                 
        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            country: { required: 'Please enter your name', },
            industry: { required: 'Please check one of the options', },
            logoname: { required: 'Please enter your Logo name' },
            sloganch: { required: 'Please check one of the options' }       
        },
        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
});
```

.validate() - to initialize the plugin (with options) once on DOM ready.

.valid() - to check validation state (boolean value) or to trigger a validation test on the form at any time.

Comment: Yes it's exactly right, i got this kind of answers from Septal besides thank you to , and have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

The answer is  :

```
$('#button4').click(function() 
  {
      // Validation
    $("#sky-form").validate({                  
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            country:  { required: true },
            industry: { required: true },
            logoname: { required: true },
            sloganch: { required: true }
        },                 
        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            country:  { required: 'Please enter your name' },
            industry: { required: 'Please check one of the options' },
            logoname: { required: 'Please enter your Logo name' },
            sloganch: { required: 'Please check one of the options' }       
        },
        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
});
```

If button code

```
<button type="button1" class="button next action-button"  id="button4">Next</button>
```

Special thanks go to Satpal who answered my question .